# Adding effect with jquery when getting data from view controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

Thanks to the help of some user, I succeed to call another view from a view using ajax and jquery.

Instead of suddently appear , I'd like to add some effect like fadedin

my code is the following

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){                     
      $(function(){
        $("#button<?php echo $this->comment_row;?>").click(function(e){
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('comment/create'); ?>",
               success: function(data) {
                $("#comment<?php echo $this->comment_row; ?>").html(data);

                }
           });
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

I can't figure out what would the syntax in this context

Thank you for your help

Comment: Make it css-ed as `display: none;` and add `.fadeIn()` after `.html(data)`

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much ajax-independent jquery question as I can tell.

Just having

`$("#comment<?php echo $this->comment_row; ?>").hide().html(data).fadeIn(400);`

instead of

`$("#comment<?php echo $this->comment_row; ?>").html(data);`

should do.

I created a simple fiddle to test it out: http://jsfiddle.net/kB7RM/1/